# Rule to delete answers with a post notice that haven't been edited

Tags: feature-request, answers, moderator-tools

I was curious to know if we can implement in the backend the removal of an answer that has a post notice of:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

With the conditions of:

- Answer has never been edited
- Score is 0 or lower
- A given timeframe has passed that allowed for editing.

The reason why I ask this is there doesn't seem to be a way moderators can track when they add a post notice to a post from what I've researched and if the OP never answers another question or chooses to not modify their answer does that still deem justification in removing the answer?

Maybe even add if the answerer does come back and make an edit and it exceeds the length by a given amount of what was there have the post notice automatically removed.

Comment: There is a mod screen for annotated posts where these get listed.  And there's a [very helpful query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/203683/post-notices-outstanding) on SEDE.

Answer (score 11):

Moderators can see annotated posts, but it's pull (we have to go look), not push (alerts).  I'm not sure that *automatic* deletion is the right answer, but an auto-flag after some period of time has passed would be consistent with some of the other auto-flags (too many comments, multiple closed questions, disputed review, etc).

Meanwhile, including the annotation date in the notice would help the community to monitor these. Right now you have to look in the post history. I know exactly one user who routinely looks up the dates and acts if the notice is old.